# Creating an Instance of java class using Gradle task?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I need to start a WireMock server from a gradle task. In java I would do something like this:

```
WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8089));
```

How can I create this wireMock Server using gradle task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in exactly the same way. Here You've a working example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:1.52'
    }
}
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.wireMockConfig
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.*
apply plugin: 'java'

task someTask {

    doLast {
        WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8089))
        println wireMockServer
    }
}
```

If an external library is to be used in `build.gradle` itself it should be added as a dependency to `buildscript` block.

Comment: After doing the above I get error : Execution failed for the task 'projectname:someTask' INSTANCE

Comment: ERROR: Execution failed for the task '<task Name>' >INSTANCE